# Off center rotation

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe a circle that is rotating, but the center of rotation is off center, thus giving the circle a sort of "wobbling" motion.

Is there a word or term to describe this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Eccentric**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eccentric)

> ...2 ... b :  located elsewhere than at the geometrical center; also :
>   having the axis or support so located

Comment: Beat me to it. Haha :)

Answer (score 2):

I've read the word *decentration* on a website where people were discussing the phenomenon of off-center records (i.e., LP records or vinyl) in which the center spindle-hole is not perfectly centered.  This phenomenon causes what is called *wow*, which is onomatopoeic for the sound the record makes while it is being played and listened to.  I don't know if the person who used the word invented it on the spot or if it's in a dictionary somewhere.

Comment: not what I was looking for, but fascinating never-the-less! cheers!

Comment: In analogue recordings, a related phenomenon is _flutter_, which is "any significant variation from the designed study rotational speed of a recording or playback mechanism, e.g., turntables and analog tape recorders (typically at 5-10 Hz rate). Heard as rapid fluctuation in pitch when played back." (Source: http://www.rane.com/par-f.html#flutter ) When I was growing up during the 1970s, ads for record players and tape recorders often referred to the degree of 'wow and flutter' (or the lack of it) of the product being marketed.